# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'value_range')

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to extend the RandomRotation class in Keras. My ultimate goal is to override a few methods in the RandomRotation class, but for right now I'm just trying to get my subclass to do the same thing that RandomRotation does: Take an image and return that image rotated at a random angle.

Here's the code for my subclass:

```
from keras.layers import RandomRotation
class ImageRotator(RandomRotation):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ImageRotator, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

My attempt to create an instance of the subclass causes the error:

```
ir_layer = ImageRotator(
    factor = (0,1),
    fill_mode="constant",
    interpolation="bilinear",
    seed=1,
    fill_value=0.0,
    value_range=(0, 255),
    data_format=None,
)
```

I don't think the value_range argument has anything to do with this problem, because I get the same error with data_format if I comment out the value_range line.

Comment: [RandomRotation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/blob/01e5c34091e67a63186d148c9cc3b9e1fbeb1dd8/keras_cv/layers/preprocessing/random_rotation.py#L84-L93) doesn't have value_range params, as it is not needed. Remove it.

Comment: Removing that along with data_format worked. The [Kreas documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/random_rotation/) must be referring to a different version.

Comment: The doc needs an update.